# How to allow an active membership with payment pending?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember

We want to start recording membership payments, but we also want memberships to become current when the start date hits even if the payment is still pending. Our members are schools paying by invoice, and membership grants the member access to a custom portal.

I have been told status override isn't good enough because it would add steps to the process to set it after entering a membership and to remove it once the membership is paid so that it will eventually expire normally.

I have investigated hook_civicrm_alterCalculatedMembershipStatus but this sees what the status would be if it wasn't pending payment- ie already what I want it to be- so I can't change it from pending there.

I'm on 4.4.13 if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

For offering membership privileges on your site, you should be able to give the same privileges to pending as current. You should be able to give discounts to pending members too.

Drupal: http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviMember+Roles+Sync

WordPress: https://github.com/tadpolecc/civi_member_sync (this seems to be working correctly on CiviCRM 4.6.6)

Comment: This is a reasonable idea. For us it would involve several small code changes (where membership status is checked for New/Current/Grace), but it might be better to check instead that the status is anything that is considered current (is_current_member). Do you think there might be any other impact in manually setting is_current_member to true for Pending, besides the ability to do this?

Comment: We already use CiviMember Roles Sync, btw. There might be some redundancy in checking for the membership too anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit which Membership Status is considered as "Current Membership"

> **[ ] Current Membership?**
>
> Should this status be considered a current membership in good standing. EXAMPLE: New, Current and Grace could all be considered 'current'.

This option is found under `Administer > CiviMember > Membership Status Rules` when editing a Membership Status there. Although the status "Pending" can't be edited, you can edit the column "MEMBER" inline in the list of status.